# PHP Sessions and iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, ip-address, cellular-network

I am developing an online membership system in PHP and I use PHP sessions to manage access to the system. This has worked well so far, however when I access the system from an iPhone or over my phones connection, the session keeps expiring. I suppose that this is because the IP addresses for cellular devices (at least on my carrier) continuously change. My question is how do i work around this? I want to be able to access this site over a cellular connection.

Cheers,

Sam

Comment: The session should be stored in a cookie, immune from new IPs. When do the sessions expire, after how much time?

Comment: A session isn't stored in a cookie. Only the session id. The server might require a session to have a static IP (not at all stupid) against session hijacking.

Comment: Check your safari settings to make sure you haven't disabled cookies, just to be sure.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, and I was wondering if you ever found a solution to this. My app also checks that the IP address doesn't change throughout the session, and this causes a real problem on data networks.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that the changing IP is actually the problem. You could test this by using the app on your iPhone when on WiFi. If it also doesn't work in that case, the issue may be WebKit-related.

If the changing IP really is the problem, it is either your server configuration that enforces a constant IP throughout a single session, or it is your server side application that does so. If you figure out which of the two, you could change it.

But, there are good reasons to enforce a constant IP for a single session, so be careful.
Also, I don't think your phone's IP will change all that often, so my guess is that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: It's definitely my IP address changing. I've run a script that logs my IP address and it changes every few seconds and the same thing has happened on other portable devices (at least with this carrier).

Comment: OK, good to be sure. (strange behavior btw, but alas). On to the second paragraph of my answer; figure out why your application currently requires a constant IP (and try to change it)